# Wait for response from emitted message?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, events, sequence

I'm having a trouble wrapping my head around following concept.

I'm sending OSC messages to query status of instruments in Ableton, so I have emmiter/receiver combo going on. Now, thing is that I'd like to avoid having to keep up some sort of global state and wrap everything around this. 
and I do communicate with Ableto in following fashion:

```
sender.emit("/live/device", queryData);
receiver.on("/live/device", function(responseData){
// process response here...
})
```

So you can tell that I'm not really sure when I got data back and cannot really sequence new queries based on responses.

What I'd like to do is to simply

```
query number of instruments on ONE certain channel
get number back 
query parameters of each instrument of that channel based on first query
receive parameters back
```

But problem is that I have no idea how to wrap eventListeners to respond to these queries, or rather how to sequence them in way that is non-blocking and yet still avoiding having some sort of global state going on.

Querying data and storing Promises to be resolved by eventListener seems like a solution, but then I'm stuck on how to pass them back to sequence.

After some research, it seems that this kind of behaving breaks the whole concept of event listeners, but then I suppose the whole point is to have some global state to keep track of what is going on, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event listeners are telling you some asynchronous action coming from a user action or any other interrupt. Depending on the API you are facing, they might have re-used event listeners for replies instead of providing a promise or callback return for the send API. If the server has multiple clients interacting with it, it might want to tell all clients at the same time when their state changes as well.

If you are sure there is no way to directly provide a callback in the send method for a reply to your request or a request does not yield a promise that resolves with the reply at some point, there are usually workarounds.

#### Option 1: Send context, receive it back

There are APIs that allow sending a "context" object or string to the API. The API then sends this context to the event listeners whenever it answers this specific question along with their payload. This way, the context part of their payload can be checked if it's the answer to the request. You could write your own little wrapper functions for a more direct send/reply pattern then.

#### Option 2: Figure out the result data, if it fits your request

If the resulting data has something specific to match on, like keys on a JSON object, it may be possible to find out what the request was.

#### Option 3: Use state on your side to keep track of everything

In most cases where I have seen such APIs, the server didn't care much about requests and only sent out their current state if it was changed by some kind of request. The client needs to replicate the state of the server by listening to all events, if it wants to show the current server state.

In most situations where I faced this issue, I thought about Option 1 or 2 but ended up with Option 3 anyways: Other clients or hardware switches might interfere with my client UI and change the server state without me listening on that change. That way I would loose information that invalidates my UI, so I would need to listen and replicate the state of the server/machine/hardware anyways.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. You are right in all cases. It later occurred to me that what I'm intending to do is way too complicated and went straight into interfacing with Python Live API instead. 
What it meant in meanwhile was to write horrible hack around Promises and store them in Array so I could "await" response from Python to be sent via OSC and move on after request was executed.  While I had sense of accomplishment when I finished this and made couple of tests, poking around Python API directly made me realize that I could do intended behavior with 3 lines of code. Lessons learned.